# system + Sys.which + local directory name with space

Tags: r, linux, windows, system

It might be very silly what I'm asking, but I'm puzzled and stuck and can't find a solution. I have an executable file in two versions (linux and windows, so e.g. helloworld and helloworld.exe). From the R prompt, I want to call a command for making it run in both OS. So I call it using system and Sys.which but the local directory where they are, it's actually with space in the name so when I do

```
system(Sys.which("/home/laptop/dont try this at home/helloworld"))
```

I got

> sh: 1: /home/laptop/dont: not found

I guess the error is in system as the shell has the real path with "\" before the space e.g.

> /home/semolo/dont\ try\ this\ at\ home

but Sys.which works with "". do you have any idea?

**Solution**
I got the solution

```
system(gsub(" ", "\\\\ ", Sys.which("/home/laptop/dont try this at home/helloworld")))
```

Comment: you may be interested by the talk on this [ticket](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16636) on R-core bugzilla.

Comment: (And, as far as I know, Sys.wich is usually used to locate a command in the path, giving it a path sounds strange)

Comment: Thanks! actually I know that Sys.which is probably not the best command for my aim but I don't know to get the right executable when you run in two different platforms

Comment: I just mean a path under Windows or Linux can't be the same, so your example sound strange. But I understand your root problem and best bet is a `gsub(' ','\ ',Sys.which('command'))` I think.

Comment: Ah ok! :) no, actually the real problem it's a little more complicated. the path is built by `paste0(file.path(DIR),"hello")`, where DIR is a environment variable set earlier. But in both cases, I got a directory with space in the name

Comment: He's my sub proposal against the built path, replace the Sys.which call by your built path, gsub will replace spaces by escaped spaces, give it a try, I can't swear it will work.

Comment: no it doesn't. but you gave me an hint. I can think something similar.

Comment: Feel free to answer yourself if you find something working cross platform, you'll have my upvote ;)